# How to display Object Iteration Array with foreach in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am integrating aupost on my website. I am getting some array in response. It seems to have used Object Iteration. I am unable to print it by foreach() loop. Kindly help me how can I display values I need

I have already tried foreach loop with normal object array print method but not working to me

when I try

```
foreach($result->service:Fontis\Auspost\Api\Postage\Domestic\Parcel\Cost\CalculationResponse:private as Newvariable)
```

or

```
foreach($result->service as Newvariable)
```

It shows me error.

My array is:-

```
Fontis\Auspost\Api\Postage\Domestic\Parcel\Cost\CalculationResponse Object (

    [service:Fontis\Auspost\Api\Postage\Domestic\Parcel\Cost\CalculationResponse:private] => Parcel Post

    [deliveryTime:Fontis\Auspost\Api\Postage\Domestic\Parcel\Cost\CalculationResponse:private] => Delivered in 2 business days

    [totalCost:Fontis\Auspost\Api\Postage\Domestic\Parcel\Cost\CalculationResponse:private] => 11.3

    [costs:Fontis\Auspost\Api\Postage\Domestic\Parcel\Cost\CalculationResponse:private] => Fontis\Auspost\Model\Postage\CostCollection Object (         

        [costs:Fontis\Auspost\Model\Postage\CostCollection:private] => Array ( 
            [0] => Fontis\Auspost\Model\Postage\Cost Object ( 
                [item:Fontis\Auspost\Model\Postage\Cost:private] => Parcel Post [cost:Fontis\Auspost\Model\Postage\Cost:private] => 11.3 
            ) 
        ) 
    ) 
)
```

Comment: missing `$` before the `Newvariable`

Comment: `I am getting some array in response`-> please add that response array in your question. Not fully, just part of it. Also `Newvariable` needs to be `$Newvariable`

Comment: "I am unable to print it by foreach() loop"  Nothing in what you're showing above _attempts_ to print/output anything

Comment: @TarakThakrar  sorry my mistake. reverted back my edit with correct modifications

Comment: $NewVariable is not working. It shows following error

Comment: `$arrayiter = new RecursiveArrayIterator($tree);
$iteriter = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($arrayiter);

foreach ($iteriter as $key => $value) {
  $d = $iteriter->getDepth();
  echo "depth=$d k=$key v=$value\n";
}` IN above snippet, replace $tree with your array and check

Comment: What you indicate is your array is not an array. That is an object. The `service` value is a string. But, they are private so I'm guess there are getter methods. Maybe try: `$service = $result->getService();` - And if you want the delivery time: `$result->getDeliveryTime();`

Comment: @quickSwap This code is not working

Comment: I tried another API that is responding in json and it's working. Anyways, thank you all for your responses.